# Heroku and Proximo Addon bin/proximo: line 36: exec: /app/vendor/dante/bin/socksify: cannot execute: Permission denied

Tags: heroku

I have installed Proximo Addon according to [official recommendation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo), but it is not gonna work because of the following reason:

Starting process with command `bin/proximo bundle exec thin start java -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar frontend/target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 5231 frontend/target/*.war`
2012-09-17T14:50:33+00:00 app[web.1]: Proxying traffic bound for 0.0.0.0/0 via Proximo host 23.21.47.211:1080
2012-09-17T14:50:33+00:00 app[web.1]: bin/proximo: line 33: /app/vendor/dante/bin/socksify: Permission denied
2012-09-17T14:50:33+00:00 app[web.1]: bin/proximo: line 33: exec: /app/vendor/dante/bin/socksify: cannot execute: Permission denied

please help me with that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `heroku addons:remove proximo` and then reinstalling with `heroku addons:add proximo`?

Also do you need to forward ALL outbound traffic or can you use it just for some specific API calls you make on your backend?

Does thin serve java apps? You might be able to just do

`bin/proximo java -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar frontend/target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 5231 frontend/target/*.war`